# XAMPP Add additional folder for storing uploads

Tags: php, apache, xampp, htdocs

I'm running XAMPP on my Window 10 machine. The default htdocs folder is

> C:\xampp\htdocs\

In this folder are stored my PHP scripts. This runs well. Now I have one script that uploads files but I don't want to store uploaded files in this default folder. I want to set another location for those uploaded files. What I need to change in httpd.conf file? Do I need to create another virtual host?

Comment: Where files are temporarily uploaded is controlled by the `upload_tmp_dir` directive in your php.ini file. When you process them you may store them anywhere you'd like to.

Comment: I understand.... thanks!